Changing selectable area of sorting filter
I have the folllowinig code:
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
# library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

#reproducible minimal data frame
YLMI <- structure(list(X = c(511L, 700L, 943L, 1402L, 1429L, 1483L, 1726L, 1834L, 1861L, 2266L), 
                       name = c("Austria", "Belgium", "Bulgaria", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", 
                                "Estonia", "Finland", "France", "Iceland"), 
                       year = c(2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L), 
                       X1 = c(6.0948572, 5.1031427, 5.145143, 4.3162856, 5.9200001, 6.0751429, 5.8771429, 
                              5.0911427, 4.8957143, 6.262857), 
                       X2 = c(5.7982831, 5.1347985, 4.1193204,3.9259963, 5.9878144, 5.8885102, 5.5807657, 
                              4.5704818, 4.8845162, 5.7285347), 
                       X3 = c(5.8720002, 5.1729999, 4.1079998, 4.7049999, 5.8794999, 6.0700002, 5.3740001, 
                              5.4159999, 5.2164998, 6.3175001), 
                       X4 = c(6.0436354, 3.9714868, 6.0058327, 4.7928214, 4.636817, 6.1576967, 5.9891138, 
                              3.3220425, 3.2921035, 4.1184382), 
                       X5 = c(6.3000154, 5.7192054, 6.5671687, 3.4370663, 6.6064062, 5.8908257, 
                              6.8782973, 4.7578831, 4.3325543, 6.2499504), 
                       X6 = c(4.9257145, 5.5085716, 4.0457144, 3.737143, 2.817143, 5.0228572, 4.0057144, 
                              3.0914288, 5.3942857, 1.7485714), 
                       X7 = c(5.2685714, 5.8857141, 5.1657143, 4.4285712, 6.6914287, 3.7942855, 
                              4.8914285, 5.7142859, 5.2857141, 5.0457144), 
                       X8 = c(5.7268553, 5.3676248, 5.7317734, 5.1083288, 4.9277864, 6.2327962, 
                              6.1439047, 5.5020885, 5.9025269, 5.6717625), 
                       X9 = c(4.7919998, 5.428, 5.1039996, 4.7199998, 5.4880004, 6.2319999, 5.1399999, 
                              5.3560004, 5.4160004, 5.3560004), 
                       X10 = c(4.7384157, 3.7913544, 4.4407039, 5.8613172, 3.5934217, 5.534936, 
                               4.0672798, 4.2066154, 4.3676648, 3.6402931), 
                       X11 = c(5.7328, 5.1810961, 5.4579573, 5.5078635, 5.3274336, 5.7784905, 
                               5.5863309, 5.2231383, 5.3318233, 5.2328768), 
                       X12 = c(5.6389961, 3.9419262, 2.6277056, 4.8922715, 4.4109187, 6.3135815, 
                               5.6100388, 6.3433652, 4.5896773, 6.6938777), 
                       W1 = c(0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 
                              0.0833), 
                       W2 = c(0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833,
                              0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833), 
                       W3 = c(0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 
                              0.0833), 
                       W4 = c(0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05), 
                       W5 = c(0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05), 
                       W6 = c(0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05), 
                       W7 = c(0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05), 
                       W8 = c(0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05), 
                       W9 = c(0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125), 
                       W10 = c(0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125), 
                       W11 = c(0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125), 
                       W12 = c(0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125), 
                       indicators = c(12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L), 
                       classes = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), 
                       index_constant = c(5.51, 4.9, 4.69, 4.78, 5.12, 5.84, 5.35, 5.02, 4.92, 5.28), 
                       ranking = c(18L, 48L, 59L, 53L, 31L, 7L, 25L, 36L, 45L, 27L)), 
                  row.names = c(511L, 700L, 943L, 1402L, 1429L, 1483L, 1726L, 1834L, 1861L, 2266L), 
                  class = "data.frame")





#helper function:
# ---- Index Calculation Based on User Weights ---- #
calculate_index_w_weights <- function(w1,w2,w3,w4) {
  
  # Obtaining weights
  weights <- array(rep(1,4)) 
  
  # Creating weight matrices to re-calculate the indicator scores.
  w1_matrix <- matrix(weights[1], nrow= 10, ncol=3)
  w2_matrix <- matrix(weights[2], nrow= 10, ncol=5)
  w3_matrix <- matrix(weights[3], nrow= 10, ncol=2)
  w4_matrix <- matrix(weights[4], nrow= 10, ncol=2)
  
  # Unnecessary for now
  YLMI[,c("W1","W2","W3")]<-YLMI[,c("W1","W2","W3")] * w1_matrix
  YLMI[,c("W4","W5","W6","W7", "W8")]<-YLMI[,c("W4","W5","W6", "W7","W8")] * w2_matrix
  YLMI[,c("W9","W10")]<-YLMI[,c("W9","W10")] * w3_matrix
  YLMI[,c("W11","W12")]<-YLMI[,c("W11","W12")] * w4_matrix
  
  ActivityState = YLMI[,c("X1", "X2", "X3")] * YLMI[,c("W1","W2","W3")] #5454x3
  WorkingConditions= YLMI[,c("X4", "X5", "X6", "X7", "X8")] * YLMI[,c("W4","W5","W6", "W7", "W8")]  #5454x5
  Education= YLMI[,c("X9", "X10")] * YLMI[,c("W9","W10")]  #5454x2
  TransitionSmoothness= YLMI[,c("X11", "X12")] * YLMI[,c("W11","W12")] #5454x2
  
  c1 <- rowSums(ActivityState) #5454 x 1 sum(x1*w1....)
  c2 <- rowSums(WorkingConditions)
  c3 <- rowSums(Education)
  c4 <- rowSums(TransitionSmoothness)
  
  w1_i <-rowSums(YLMI[,c("W1","W2","W3")])
  w2_i <-rowSums(YLMI[,c("W4","W5","W6","W7", "W8")])
  w3_i <-rowSums(YLMI[,c("W9","W10")])
  w4_i <-rowSums(YLMI[,c("W11","W12")])
  
  # weighted_index  = YLMI_Nominator / sum_weights
  ActivityState = c1 / w1_i
  WorkingConditions = c2 / w2_i
  Education = c3 / w3_i
  TransitionSmoothness = c4 / w4_i
  
  # Category weighting
  weights_category <- array(rep(0.25,4)) 
  
  # User input on weights
  w_unit <- 1 / (w1+w2+w3+w4)
  weights_category[1] <- w_unit * w1
  weights_category[2] <- w_unit * w2
  weights_category[3] <- w_unit * w3
  weights_category[4] <- w_unit * w4
  
  w1_cat_matrix <- matrix(weights_category[1], nrow= 10, ncol=1)
  w2_cat_matrix <- matrix(weights_category[2], nrow= 10, ncol=1)
  w3_cat_matrix <- matrix(weights_category[3], nrow= 10, ncol=1)
  w4_cat_matrix <- matrix(weights_category[4], nrow= 10, ncol=1)
  
  categories <- data.frame(ActivityState, WorkingConditions, Education, TransitionSmoothness,
                           W1_C=w1_cat_matrix, W2_C=w2_cat_matrix, W3_C= w3_cat_matrix, W4_C=w4_cat_matrix)
  
  categories[is.na(categories) == TRUE] = 0
  
  # If category value is zero, then no weight assigned to that category for the index calculation.
  categories <- within(categories, W1_C[ActivityState == 0] <- 0)
  categories <- within(categories, W2_C[WorkingConditions == 0] <- 0)
  categories <- within(categories, W3_C[Education == 0] <- 0)
  categories <- within(categories, W4_C[TransitionSmoothness == 0] <- 0)
  
  weights_category_sum <-rowSums(categories[,c("W1_C","W2_C","W3_C","W4_C")])
  
  YLMI_Nominator1=categories[,c("ActivityState")] * categories[,c("W1_C")]
  YLMI_Nominator2=categories[,c("WorkingConditions")] * categories[,c("W2_C")]
  YLMI_Nominator3=categories[,c("Education")] * categories[,c("W3_C")]
  YLMI_Nominator4=categories[,c("TransitionSmoothness")] * categories[,c("W4_C")]
  
  YLMI_Nominator = YLMI_Nominator1 + YLMI_Nominator2 + YLMI_Nominator3 + YLMI_Nominator4
  index  = YLMI_Nominator / weights_category_sum
  
  YLMI["weighted_index"]<-index
  YLMI["ActivityState"]<-ActivityState
  YLMI["WorkingConditions"]<-WorkingConditions
  YLMI["Education"]<-Education
  YLMI["TransitionSmoothness"]<-TransitionSmoothness
  
  #creating subset for single indicator scores
  YLMI_IScores <- data.frame(
    Country = YLMI[, c("name")],
    Year = YLMI[, c("year")],
    Classes = YLMI[, c("classes")],
    Index = YLMI[, c("index_constant")],
    Weighted_Index = YLMI[, c("weighted_index")],
    ActivityState=YLMI[, c("ActivityState")],
    WorkingConditions=YLMI[, c("WorkingConditions")],
    Education=YLMI[, c("Education")],
    TransitionSmoothness=YLMI[, c("TransitionSmoothness")],
    UnemploymentRate = YLMI[, c("X1")],
    RelaxedUnemploymentRate = YLMI[, c("X2")],
    NEETRate = YLMI[, c("X3")],
    TemporaryWorkersRate = YLMI[, c("X4")],
    InvoluntaryPartTimeWorkersRate = YLMI[, c("X5")],
    AtypicalWorkingHoursRate = YLMI[, c("X6")],
    InWorkatRiskofPovertyRate = YLMI[, c("X7")],
    VulnerableEmploymentRate =  YLMI[, c("X8")],
    FormalEducationandTrainingRate = YLMI[, c("X9")],
    SkillsMismatchRate = YLMI[, c("X10")],
    RelativeUnemploymentRatio = YLMI[, c("X11")],
    LongTermUnemploymentRate = YLMI[, c("X12")])
  
  # Deleting rows if calculated index is NaN
  YLMI_IScores <- YLMI_IScores[!is.na(YLMI_IScores$Index), ]
  
  YLMI_IScores[is.na(YLMI_IScores) == TRUE] = "-"
  return(YLMI_IScores)
}

##server##
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  #scoreboard
  
  #table layout for scoreboard
  sketch <- htmltools:: withTags(
    table(
      class = "display",
      thead(
        tr(
          th(colspan = 3, "Selection", style = "border-right: solid 2px;"),
          th(colspan = 2, "Aggregate Index", style = "border-right: solid 2px;", bgcolor="#f72a66"),
          th(colspan = 4, "Sub-Index Values by Dimension", style = "border-right: solid 2px;"),
          th(colspan = 3, "Dimension: Activity State", style = "border-right: solid 2px;"),
          th(colspan = 5, "Dimension: Working Conditions", style = "border-right: solid 2px;"),
          th(colspan = 2, "Dimension: Education", style = "border-right: solid 2px;"),
          th(colspan = 2, "Dimension: Transition Smoothness", style = "border-right: solid 2px;")
        ),
        
        tr(
          th("Country"),
          th("Year"),
          th("Classes", style = "border-right: solid 2px;"),
          th("Index", bgcolor="#fdb9c4"),
          th("Weighted Index", bgcolor="#fdb9c4", style = "border-right: solid 2px;"),
          th(div("Activity State", br(), br(), br(), br(), selectInput("w_1",
                                                                 label = "Weight",
                                                                 choices = 0:3,
                                                                 selected = 1, 
                                                                 width = "60px"
          )), bgcolor = "#fff9ee"),
          th(div("Working Conditions", br(), br(), br(), br(), selectInput("w_2",
                                                               label = "Weight",
                                                               choices = 0:3,
                                                               selected = 1, 
                                                               width = "60px"
          )), bgcolor = "#fff9ee"),
          th(div("Education", br(), br(), br(), br(), br(), selectInput("w_3",
                                                            label = "Weight",
                                                            choices = 0:3,
                                                            selected = 1, 
                                                            width = "60px"
          )), bgcolor = "#fff9ee"),
          th(div("Transition Smoothness", br(), br(), br(), br(), selectInput("w_4",
                                                                  label = "Weight",
                                                                  choices = 0:3,
                                                                  selected = 1, 
                                                                  width = "60px"
          )), bgcolor = "#fff9ee", style = "border-right: solid 2px;"),
          th(div("Unemployment Rate", br(), br(), br(), br(), selectInput("w_4",
                                                                          label = "Weight",
                                                                          choices = 0:3,
                                                                          selected = 1,
                                                                          width = "60px"))),
          th("Relaxed Unemployment Rate"),
          th("NEET Rate", style = "border-right: solid 2px;"),
          th("Temporary Workers Rate"),
          th("Involuntary Part Time Workers Rate"),
          th("Atypical Working Hours Rate"),
          th("In Work at Risk of Poverty Rate"),
          th("Vulnerable Employment Rate", style = "border-right: solid 2px;"),
          th("Formal Educationand Training Rate"),
          th("Skills Mismatch Rate", style = "border-right: solid 2px;"),
          th("Relative Unemployment Ratio"),
          th("Long Term Unemployment Rate")
        )
      )
    )
  )
  
  #data filtering based on user input
  filterData <- reactive({
    
    w1 <- ifelse(is.null(input$w_1), yes = 1, no = as.integer(input$w_1))
    w2 <- ifelse(is.null(input$w_2), yes = 1, no = as.integer(input$w_2))
    w3 <- ifelse(is.null(input$w_3), yes = 1, no = as.integer(input$w_3))
    w4 <- ifelse(is.null(input$w_4), yes = 1, no = as.integer(input$w_4))
    
    
    YLMI_IScores <- calculate_index_w_weights(w1,w2,w3,w4)
    
    rows <- (YLMI_IScores$Country %in% input$country_scb) & (YLMI_IScores$Classes %in% input$country_classes_scb)
    data <- YLMI_IScores[rows,, drop = FALSE]
    data
  })
  
  # receive initial dataset only once to avoid re-rendering the table
  initData <- reactiveVal()
  observeEvent(filterData(), {
    initData(filterData())
  }, once = TRUE)
  
  output$scb_table <- DT::renderDT({
    datatable(initData(), rownames = FALSE, container = sketch, escape = FALSE,
              options = list(info = TRUE, order= list(3,"dsc"), pageLength = 50, ordering = TRUE,
                             columnDefs = list(list(targets = "_all", className = "dt-center")),
                             preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
                             drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')
              )
    ) %>%
      formatStyle(c(3,5,9,12,17,19,21), `border-right` = "solid 2px") %>%
      formatStyle(columns = "Index", backgroundColor = "#fdb9c4") %>%
      formatStyle(columns = "Weighted_Index", backgroundColor = "#fdb9c4") %>%
      formatStyle(columns = "ActivityState", backgroundColor = "#fff9ee") %>%
      formatStyle(columns = "WorkingConditions", backgroundColor = "#fff9ee") %>%
      formatStyle(columns = "Education", backgroundColor = "#fff9ee") %>%
      formatStyle(columns = "TransitionSmoothness", backgroundColor = "#fff9ee") %>%
      formatRound(columns = c(4:21), digits = 2)
  }, server = TRUE)
  
  scb_table_proxy <- dataTableProxy(outputId = "scb_table", session = session, deferUntilFlush = TRUE)
  
  observeEvent(filterData(), {
    replaceData(proxy = scb_table_proxy, data = filterData(), resetPaging = FALSE, rownames = FALSE) # must repeat rownames = FALSE see ?replaceData and ?dataTableAjax
  })
  
}

##ui ##
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML(
    c(
      "table.dataTable thead > tr > th.sorting::after {",
      "  top: 94% !important;",
      "}",
      "table.dataTable thead > tr > th.sorting::before {",
      "  bottom: 6% !important;",
      "}"
    )
  ))),
  sidebarLayout(
    #scoreboard
    sidebarPanel(
      pickerInput(
        inputId = "country_scb",
        label = "Select country/countries",
        selected = unique(sort(YLMI$name)), # Default selecting all the countries here! TODO
        choices = unique(sort(YLMI$name)),
        multiple = TRUE,
        options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)
      ),
      awesomeCheckboxGroup(
        inputId = "country_classes_scb",
        label = "Filter countries by data availability:", 
        choices = unique(sort(YLMI$classes)),
        selected = unique(sort(YLMI$classes)),                         
      )
    ),
    mainPanel( 
      # Show data table   
      DT::dataTableOutput("scb_table")
      
    )
  )
)



shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

That produces the following table

The position of the sorting filter is exactly where i want. The only problem is that, when clicking on the drop-down menu of each variable to change the weight, the entire column gets sorted even if i don't want. The area of the sorting menu is reactive for all the header of the column, but my goal is to make sensitive only the part where there are the arrows to sort the column.
How can I achieve this?

Your example code is far away from being minimal.

Your project seems to reproduce that output on my device, but I fail to understand what is considered the problem.  "goal is to make sensitive only the part where there are the arrows to sort the column.", You need to expand on that statement. If the weights change in a particular column, how can the other results that depend on the values of that column not be expected to change and the entire table get resorted?
